# Looking for a clever way to differentiate objects

Tags: unity, game-design, sprites

I have a lot of cubes in my game (2d squares) and I decided to add some skins to them. However the colors that they have don't really make them look appealing.

For example, I have this sprite:

[image]

Here is how the squares look with that particular sprite:

[image]

As you can see, they don't really look that great with all these bright colors.

Is there any way that I can make this look better, but for the users to still be able to differentiate between the different cubes?

Comment: Add icons/decals to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

- Colours (what you did already)
- Add 'tags' (like a label that has been stuck to it) at different positions
- Add letters or numbers as decals
- Add different images
- Instead of having only box crates, you could add steel crates, rock blocks
- Different shapes
- You could make them slightly *move!* Like Fat Albert's gang, you could give each type of cube it's own way to move (e.g. one rotates every 2 seconds, one performs a half rotation each second, one half-rotate and comes back, one pulses like a beating heart, one fades like a ghost, etc...)
- With the lore of your game, give them names, personalities and visuals and make them act as such (e.g. instead of *Green Cube*, call it Hope, make it move softly and give it a look of a soft and comforting joy, and instead of *Red Cube*, call it Rage, make it pulse violently like a pounding fist, while giving it the look of something angry, like your worst grade school teacher).

This last idea really comes down to "*Why do I have different coloured cubes?*" If there is no reason, there is no reason to have different coloured cubes and differentiate them, as this could confuse some players. If you want to have different coloured cubes, find a game-design reason to have different coloured (or whatever you'd like to change their look for).

Once you find that reason, this will help you define the cube personalities, and then expand on them, and then further expand on your game's background story.

If your game does not have a story/background, this could be a nice reason to develop one (some players like to follow through the story of the game, sometimes more than to play the game *per se*), and if you already have one, try to make the colour/personalities complement it.

---

*Keep in mind that your players will want to play the game, not be bothered by the story: make sure they know there is one and give them access to it if they want to live it, but don't force them to have to go through it in order to play.*